# Drop Annotation in Google Map From iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to drop Annotation in Google Map From My iOS App.i have Latitude and Longitude, also i have one button called "MAP",When i Press Map button , that should take users to Safari and Load Google Map with annotation in my Latitude and Longitude or Google Map Application with Annotation in my Latitude and Longitude.

i tried the following code

```
NSString *urlGoogle  = @"https://www.google.co.in/maps/search/8.558096,76.880744/@8.558096,76.880744,17z?hl=en"
;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlGoogle]];
```

But It Works intermittently. It does not work always. Sometime it loads the Map correctly. Sometime safari just shows "Loading bar", then nothing happens.. Please anyone help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can't do anything about this. As it happens in `Google Map iOS app`. Though other solution is to integrate Google Map in your application rather than launching outside, see here for help https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

Comment: Perfectly working..Great..Thanks dude...